# Why would azure be restarting website when i do a deployment slot swap?

Tags: azure

I've a .net 4.5 website running on Azure Websites. I've a staging deployment set up. I warm up both sites and then i run the swap process (both from azure portal and from Azure powershell). No matter what I try the swapping process restarts my websites (both) and they take about 3 minutes to boot up.

I was under the impression the deployment swapping was supposed to keep the websites "warm" and have no down time? My websites are unusuable for about 3 minutes!

As far as I can tell both production and staging slots have the same application settings etc.

Comment: Are you using Application Settings marked as "slot"? If yes, they cause the web app to restart when swapping.
Here you can find more details: http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/